# Security for XML Database

Tags: c#, .net, xml, security

In one of the project we are using XML as database. Later we realized that security of the data is issue. User of the application can modify any data using note pad. Below are the couple of things we can do to secure the database.

Note that application is written in dot net.

1. Encrypt the entire xml, program will decrypt and use it, while saving encrypt and save it.(Performance issue)
2. Using dot net assembly we can encrypt the nodes.(Performance issue and lots of code need to be written to encrypt and decrypt the notes.

Is there any best way to secure XML in such way that user can not simply modify using notepad.?

Comment: Win app? Web app? Which db? ...

Comment: And where will you store the decryption key, keeping in mind the user basically needs read access to it since they are running the program? Sounds like you need some kind of external service to control the data access.

Comment: Not clear are you worried about integrity or security? If the latter at what level. Can't see, can't change, different privilege levels?

Comment: It is desktop app written in c# .net. Storing the data in plain XML file. Not using any RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server is an option and your main goal is to prevent snooping in the data, you could leverage SQL Server's XML handling and built-in encryption capabilities (e.g. certificates, TDE, etc) for handling the encryption. This will eliminate most of the manual work you are describing.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx

If the data needs to be encrypted throughout the entire process (for example, when it is in the application's memory space) or if the data is on the user's machine, then SQL-based encryption will not be practical or sufficient.

> Using dot net assembly we can encrypt the nodes.(Performance issue and
>   lots of code need to be written to encrypt and decrypt the notes.

I'm not saying that this is the correct solution because you haven't provided enough detail. However, I think that you are operating under two invalid assumptions.

- Encryption in .NET is very robust and can be performed with less than 100 lines of code. You can use a standard encryption algorithm or integrate with Windows Certificate Services.
- There is of course a performance impact, but modern CPUs do a superb job handling the math required by encryption. Unless the files are huge and/or you are processing hundreds of them every second, I would not base the design on performance concerns.

Ultimately, if the data resides on the user's machine, the biggest concern will be the location and security of the key.

Comment: He said it's a XML db. Is it possible for SQL server to use raw xml files as storage medium?

Comment: @walther - ugh...completely misread that part of the question and saw "SQL" in there somehow. Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, SQL CAN be used to reference external files using `FILESTREAM`. Might be an option.

Comment: I am just using Plain text XML file for storing data. Not using Any data base management systems.

Comment: @Saran - then the second part of my post is relevant: 1) encrypting it with c# isn't hard or resource-intensive (unless it is in large quantities) and 2) you will need to manage the encryption key. If all you care about is preventing casual snooping, you could just obfuscate the data.